# column wise array to row wise array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have three array column wise using which i am trying to create array row wise using java-script like this. Do i need to traverse through complete data?

```
what i have 

var a=new Array("1","2","3","4");

var b=new Array("5","6","7","8");

var c=new Array("9","10","11","12");


what i want to create using the above array

var d=new Array("1","5","9");

var e=new Array("2","6","10");

var f=new Array("3","7","11");

var g=new Array("4","8","12");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are denoting each array by different variable names, then the task becomes tedious.
On the other hand, if you store them in a single `2-Dimensional` array it can be accomplished easily.

Say the first array is alternatively declared as follows:

```
var total_array = new Array(
                   new Array("1","2","3","4"),
                   new Array("5","6","7","8"),
                   new Array("9","10","11","12")
                  );
```

Now you can use a simple `for` loop to store the contents in a new `2d` array column wise.

```
var new_array = new Array(4);
for(var i=0; i<4; i++)
      new_array[i] = new Array(3);

//now copy the contents...

for(var i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for(var j=0; j<4; j++)
    {
         new_array[j][i] = total_array[i][j];
    }
}
```

And after this for loop you have the new array containing the column-wise data in each row.